Compare two cells in Excel with Power Automate
Within power automate, I'd like to compare a column with a fixed cell in an Excel spreadsheet (compare dates with current date). If the target date exceeds the current date, do something.
It seems like 1st lesson, but I can't find the expression how to compare to cells in power automate.
How can this be done?

As shown in the screenshot, I tried to figure out the expression to call a single cell, to compare it with the column, But I couldn't find it.

We use date functions to compare dates.
You can use utcNow() to get current time stamp. There are other functions like StartofDay(), addHours(), formatDateTime(), etc, which provide more access to date functions.
For more: Microsoft — Dynamics 365 Community — Power Automate Fundamentals # 11: Usage of Add Days in Power Automate

Unfortunately utcNow() doesn’t work. Excel stores the dates as numbers, starting from 01.01.1900 and counting each day until today (number 45527 for 23.08.2024). That’s why utcNow(‘DD.MM.YYYY’) wouldn’t work either.
In general, does anybody know whether it’s possible to compare a single cell in excel or can power automate only handle lists?

Excel stores the number of dates from "1899-12-30" as dateTime. Now, you have to add this number of days to retrieve the actual date, and then you can proceed to your comparisons.
addDays('1899-12-30',int(item()?['Date']),'yyyy-MM-dd')

Once done, you can use it for comparison for today, specific date, older than, later than and so on.



